# Strange behaviour during mid-swipe back

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm experiencing a strange glitch where I can use the previous view controller before the top view controller has been dismissed.

At my main view controller I have a table view with the delegate function didSelectRowAtIndexPath. The function is below:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("commentsSegue", sender: self)
}
```

This works great, however if I am already showing this screen, I can select it again if I half-swipe back. This is sort of hard to explain but you can use a finger to swipe back and the other to select a cell on the main viewcontroller. This creates another segue to a new "commentsSegue". I can do this as many times as I like and it will action many segues.

I have tried to overcome this by using

```
if (self.presentingViewController?.presentedViewController == self) {
```

and also

```
if (self.navigationController?.topViewController.title == self.title) {
```

But both of these functions return the main viewcontroller as the active view controller instead of the "commentsSegue" controller.

How can I stop this behaviour from occurring?

Answer (score 0):

On swipe create a `Notification` which check if your destination controller `.isKindOfClass` your current one. If not , make the segue.